# Problem with spherical coordiantes

Tags: geometry

So I'm trying to convert

$ x^{2} $+$ y^{2} $ = 9, into spherical coordinates, here is my process :

$ x^{2} $+$ y^{2} $+$ z^{2} $ = 9+$ z^{2} $

$ \rho^{2} $ = 9 + $ \rho^{2} $$ cos^{2} $($ \phi $)

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I wouldn't say you're wrong, you're just not done. Try using $\sin^2 \phi +\cos^2\phi =1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=9$$

can be written as $(3\cos\alpha\sin\beta, 3\cos\alpha\cos\beta, 3\sin\alpha)$

Here we need $\sin\alpha=0$ and can safely set $\cos\alpha=\pm1$

Comment: The question asks about $x^2+y^2=9$, not $x^2+y^2+z^2=9...$

Comment: @Semiclassical, What if $x=\pm3\sin\beta,y=\pm3\cos\beta,z=0$